# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied, While opening a file

Tags: python, windows, file-io

I have a Python script which looks for any changes in a folder(addition/deletion) of files.
I am looking for any new files added and wants to open them and read some data from them.

The code is

```
# Utility to check for any new jobs

import os
import win32file
import win32event
import win32con
import string

path= r"C:\Users\dZONE\Desktop\py"

change_handle = win32file.FindFirstChangeNotification      (path,0,win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME)

try:

  old_path_contents = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path)])
while 1:
  result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject (change_handle, 500)


if result == win32con.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
  new_path_contents = dict ([(f, None) for f in os.listdir (path)])
  added = [f for f in new_path_contents if not f in old_path_contents]
  #deleted = [f for f in old_path_contents if not f in new_path_contents]
  if added: print "Added: ", ", ".join (added)
  #if deleted: print "Deleted: ", ", ".join (deleted)
  # My open
  print "Len" , len(added)
  for item in added:
   print item
   ad=open(item,'r')
   print ad.read()

  old_path_contents = new_path_contents
  win32file.FindNextChangeNotification (change_handle)

 finally:
   win32file.FindCloseChangeNotification (change_handle)
```

When i am trying to open the file it is giving me the IO Error 13. Though i have rights on the folder and the file. I wrote another test code and  tried opening the same file directly giving the file name to open() and it did worked.

If anyone can point out the mistake i am doing would be really appreciated.

EDIT: Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dZONE\Desktop\py\util.py", line 50, in <module>
ad=open(item,'r')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ad.sjs_hdr'
```

P.S I am new to python so maybe i am making some really silly mistake
thanks

Comment: Is 'ad.sjs_hdr' a file or a folder?

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko It is a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.listdir()` method gives you filenames without paths only, you are probably trying to open a file in the *current* directory, not in the directory named by `path`.

You have to use the [`os.path.join` function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to put `path` and `item` together:

```
for item in added:
    print item
    fullfilename = os.path.join(path, item)
    ad=open(fullfilename,'r')
    print ad.read()
```