# Errno13, Permission denied when trying to read file

Tags: python, file, readfile, dir

I have created a small python script. With that I am trying to read a txt file but my access is denied resolving to an no.13 error, here is my code:

```
import time
import os

destPath = 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder(13)'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(destPath):

f=open(destPath, 'r')
.....
```

Comment: is your file open already in windows I got for this...please try after closing the file/files

Comment: No unfortunately for me it is closed, netherless, i closed and reopened cmd but still nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I remade the way I was reading the file and it worked, though I am pretty sure there are more ways to do this but anyway. I changed `f=open(destPath, 'r')` for `os.path.exists(destPath)` `f=os.access(destPath, os.R_OK)`

Comment: Not certain if it's what you need, but these questions look similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215716/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-trying-to-open-hidden-file-in-w-mod  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924981/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-while-opening-a-file    Other than that, are you certain you have read permission ? Also, if destPath is a directory, why are you trying to open & read it? If it isn't one, why are you passing it to os.walk?

Comment: `f = open(filename, 'r')` not `destPath` to open

Comment: No destPath not filename, at least that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the name, I'm guessing that `destPath` is a directory, not a file. You can do a `os.walk` or a `os.listdir` on the directory, but you can't `open` it for reading. You can only call `open` on a file.

Maybe you meant to call `open` on one or more of the items from `files`

Comment: When I try to `open` a directory, I get an `IsADirectoryError` exception, which is errno 21 on my UNIX machine.

Comment: Thanks!  trying to open a DIR is exactly my problem also.  Doh

Answer (score 0):

1:
I take it you are trying to access a file to get what's inside but don't want to use a direct path and instead want a variable to denote the path. This is why you did the `destPath` I'm assuming.

From what I've experienced the issue is that you are skipping a simple step.  What you have to do is INPUT the location **then** use `os.CHDIR` to go to that location. and **finally** you can use your 'open()'.

From there you can either use `open('[direct path]','r')` or `destPath2 = 'something'` then `open(destPath2, 'r')`.

To summarize:  You want to get the path then NAVIGATE to the path, then get the 'filename' (can be done sooner or not at all if using a direct path for this), then open the file.

2:  You can also try adding an "r" in front of your path. r'[path]' for the raw line in case python is using the "\" for something else.

3:  Try deleting the "c:/" and switching the / to \ or vice versa.

That's all I got, hope one of them helps! :-)

Answer (score -2):

I got this issue when trying to create a file in the path -C:/Users/anshu/Documents/Python_files/Test_files . I discovered python couldn't really access the directory that was under the user's name.
So, I tried creating the file under the directory - C:/Users/anshu/Desktop .
I was able to create files in this directory through python without any issue.

Comment: your answer is not relevant to above question, the question is about reading a file and you posting about the "create file". Please read the wiki of how to answer questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer