# I am trying to read an Excel file into Spyder, and I am getting an "operation not permitted" error

Tags: python, dataframe

Error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/lilianude/Documents/UDE LILIAN/GENG 8900 Data Mining/Datasets/Original Datasets Without Labels/Credit.xlsx'

Answer (score 1):

The file might be open somewhere through out your system, please check that and close that file to use it in another program.

Check this might help -- [Errno13, Permission denied when trying to read file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478266/errno13-permission-denied-when-trying-to-read-file)

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer. I have come across this many times. `Windows` locks open files so that they cannot be double edited. If you opened the same in excel it would actually prompt for `read only` or `notify when available`..